# display-buffer-alist does not seem to work

Tags: window-splitting, display-buffer-alist

The aim is to display a buffer named `*navigator*` in a side window at the bottom.
I have following code.

```el
;; the function toggle-navigator is in another directory being imported as a package.
;; it is a work in progress
;; (package-install-file "/Users/user/projects/navigator/package.el")
(defun toggle-navigator ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((new-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*navigator*")))
    (switch-to-buffer new-buffer)
    (dolist (entry (get-files-and-directories "/Users/user"))
      (insert entry "\n"))
    (goto-char (point-min))))

;; in init.el
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
         '("\\*navigator\\*"
           (display-buffer-in-side-window)
           (window-height . 0.25)
           (side . bottom)
           (slot . -1)))

;; multi term
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
         '("\\*vterm*\\*"
           (display-buffer-in-side-window)
           (window-height . 0.25)
           (side . bottom)
           (slot . -1)))

(defvar vterm-count 0)

(defun my/vterm-new ()
  "Create new instance of vterm"
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (setq vterm-count (+ vterm-count 1))
    (vterm)
    (rename-buffer (format "*vterm%d*" vterm-count))))
```

The `vterm` part works as expected. But the navigator buffer always opens fullscreen instead of in side window.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch-to-buffer` isn't subject to those rules.  That's not what it's for.  What that function does is:

> Display buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME in the selected window.

Use `pop-to-buffer` (or of course just `display-buffer` if you don't mean to select it) to tell Emacs to use `display-buffer-alist` and friends to decide which window to use.